# Permissão negada ao criar pasta

Tags: c#

Estava criando uma aplicação que precisa criar uma pasta na `System32` ou na própria pasta do windows, só que precisa de permissão e da o erro:'`O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Windows\pasta' foi negado.`'
Alguém sabe como posso conseguir criar sem a permissão?

```
string diretorio = @"C:\Windows\pasta";
        if (!Directory.Exists(diretorio))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(diretorio);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa acessar o seu programa como Administrador (botão direito do mouse, *Executar como Administrador*), ou se estiver *debugando* tem que fazer o mesmo para abrir o Visual Studio.

Se quiser garantir que sua aplicação sempre será executada como Administrador, adicione um arquivo *manifest* no seu projeto e preenche o atributo `level` do elemento `requestedExecutionLevel` com o valor `requireAdministrator`:

```xml
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]